# Having Actions Performed Upon Button Press

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm a bit of a newbie with Rails and I have what I believe is a pretty simple question. I'm designing a voting application. Upon pressing a button, the number of votes increases by one. The controller method code looks like:

```
def vote
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @item.increment(:votes)
  @item.save
  redirect_to :show
end
```

The button has the code of:

```
%= button_to "Vote",  :method => "Vote" %
```

This seems to be where my error occurs. It's trying to go to a url of /:id?method=Vote when I'm just trying to get the application to run the method then return back to the show page. Any suggestions are very appreciated! I'm convinced this is an issue of not fully understanding the concept of routing, but honestly I'm a little stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:method` pertains to the HTTP verb, and default is `:post`, but since you are updating an object, you probably want to use `:put`

```
button_to "Vote", vote_item_path(@item), :method => :put
```

where `@item` is your `Item` object. You also need to define your route

```
put 'items/:id/vote' => 'items#vote', :as => :vote_item
```

To clarify what is going on here, `vote_item_path(@item)` will generate the URL `items/1/vote` if `@item.id = 1`

Comment: Thanks for that! I seem to understand the logic behind it. I guess my issue is that when I hit the button, I want it to run some code then basically refresh the page. This method seems to want to create a whole new page though.